# Retrieving perimeter points of point in Python list comprehension

Tags: python, list

Given `p(y,x)`, how do I retrieve perimeter points with offset 1 `[(y-1,x), (y+1,x+1), (y,x+1),(y+1,x+1), (y+1,x), (y-1,x-1), (y,x-1), (y-1,x-1)]` in list comprehension in Python?

```
|------------|----------|------------|
| (y-1, x-1) | (y-1,x)  | (y-1, x+1) |
|------------|----------|------------| 
| (y, x-1)   | (y,x)    | (y, x+1)   |
|------------|----------|------------|
| (y+1, x-1) | (y+1, x) | (y+1, x+1) |
|------------|----------|------------|
```

Comment: What's the value of `p(y,x)`?

Comment: Any arbitrary value....

Comment: You can't get certain coordinates from an arbitrary value.

Comment: Does it matter if the points are in a different order?

Comment: They are supposed to be relative to `p(y,x)`.  So for `p(0,0)`, would return `[(0,1),(1,1),(1,0),(1,-1),(0,-1),(-1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1)]`

Comment: @chepner - order is not important

Comment: We could do it if we were given `(y,x)`, but not if we're only given some arbitrary meaningless `p(y,x)` value.

Comment: Why do you want some points twice, and why do you want a list comprehension?

Comment: @KellyBundy - Where do you see points twice? It doesn't need to be list comprehension, but I thought there was going to be an easy way to do it. Maybe I am wrong....

Comment: `(y+1,x+1)` and `(y-1,x-1)` appear twice in your desired list.

Comment: How is that the same point? If input point is `(7,8)`, `(y+1,x+1)` would return `(8,9)` and `(y-1,x-1)` would return `(6,7)`.

Comment: Yes, but `(y+1,x+1)`=`(8,9)` appears twice in your list and `(y-1,x-1)`=`(6,7)` appears twice in your list.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it....

Comment: I don't see how [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydnND.png) is hard to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun, using complex numbers:

```
[(round(z.imag), round(z.real))
 for a in range(8)
 for z in [complex(x, y) + 1j**(a/2)]]
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this works?

Comment: @konichiwa The powers of the imaginary number i (written in Python as `1j`) form the unit circle. I just take the eight powers at angles 0, 45, 90, ..., 315 degrees, which gives me the desired deltas to add to the input coordinate (just needs rounding to ints then).

Comment: Beautiful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The perimeter points are all of the form `(x+dx, y+dy)` for suitable values of `dx` and `dy`.

What are those suitable values? `1`, `0`, and `-1`.

```
from itertools import product


pp = [(x+dx, y+dy) for dx, dy in product([-1, 0, 1], repeat=2) if dx != 0 or dy != 0]
```

The filter prevent you from adding `(x,y)` itself to the result (i.e., when `dx == 0` and `dy == 0`).

Comment: This is only returning 4 points, not 8...

Comment: @konichiwa You must've changed the code.

Comment: Nope, still getting 4 points. There is also a problem with a bracket in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I used `and` when I should have used `or`.